# With Elasticsearch, how to use an OR instead of AND within filter->terms query?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have this following query with elastic:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [{
                "terms": {
                    "participants.group": ["group1","group2"]
                }
            }, {
                "range": {
                    "recordDate": {
                        "gte": "2020-05-14 00:00:00.000",
                        "lte": "2020-07-22 20:30:56.566"
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Currently, this finds records with participants with group "group1" **and** "group2".
How to change the query so it finds records with participants from "group1" **or** "group2?

Is it possible to do it **without** changing the structure of the query?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the field `participants.group` is of [`keyword`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html) type and not [`text`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/text.html) type.

Assuming that, the query you have roughly translates to `(group1) or (group2) or (group1 and group2)`.

All you need to do is modify the query as below and add a `must_not` clause like below:

```
POST my_filter_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "range": {
                    "recordDate": {
                      "gte": "2020-05-14 00:00:00.000",
                      "lte": "2020-07-22 20:30:56.566"
                    }
                }
              }
            ], 
            "should": [
              {
                "terms": {
                  "participants.group": ["group1", "group2"]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ], 
      "must_not": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "participants.group": "group1"
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "participants.group": "group2"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Let me know if that works!